# The image of a closed subgroup is closed when the kernel is finite

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

Let $\varphi:G\rightarrow H$ be a continuous homomorphism between topological groups $G$ and $H$ and assume that $\ker \varphi $ is finite. Let $K<G$ be a closed subgroup. How to show that $Im (K)$ is closed subgroup of $H$?

Comment: Look at the proof of Hunter's Lemma. For the pseudovariety $F$ of all finite groups.

Comment: what is Hunter's Lemma? can you please provide a reference ?

Comment: Robert P. Hunter, Certain finitely generated compact zero-dimensional semigroups, J. Austral. Math. Soc., Ser. A 44 (1988), 265–270. Here is the original paper. You can find others related to group theory as well

Comment: Jorge Almeida, Profinite semigroups and applications, Structural Theory of Automata, Semigroups, and Universal Algebra (New York) (Valery B. Kudryavtsev and Ivo G. Rosenberg, eds.), NATO Science Series II: Mathematics, Physics and Chemistry, vol. 207, Springer, 2005, Proceedings of the NATO Advanced Study Institute on Structural Theory of Automata, Semigroups and Universal Algebra, Montral, Qubec, Canada, 7-18 July 2003, pp. 1–45. This is another reference with more explanation

Comment: This need not be true. Consider $G\ne 1$ with discrete topology, $H=G$ with trivial topology, $\varphi=id_G$. Then $K=1$ but $\varphi(K)<H$ is not closed. Do you have further assumptions?

Comment: Further assumptions: $G$ is connected!

Comment: OK, then take $G=({\mathbb R},+)$ with the standard topology and $H=G$ with trivial topology.

Comment: @MoisheKohan in your last comment the identity map is not continuous.

Comment: A counterexample with $G$ connected is the embedding of a dense line into a torus.

Comment: @YCor: The question was about homomorphisms $\phi: G\to H$ (not $H\to G$). When $H$ has trivial topology, such $\phi$  will be always continuous. Of course, your example is more "interesting".

Comment: @MoisheKohan ah, I understood trivial topology meant discrete topology.

Comment: @YCor: Trivial topology usually means the topology with just two open sets. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology

Comment: @MoisheKohan yes of course I eventually understood... it's always interesting when it's not trivial to guess the meaning of "trivial"...!